# Validar linha javascript

Tags: javascript

Pessoal estou tentando fazer um validação linha a linha em uma table da seguinte forma: Se o produto for marcado como sim em um fornecedor ele nao pode ser marcado para outro fornecedor. Alguem pode me ajudar por favor? Segue modelo...

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $('#selectProduto').change(function(){
    $('#msg').html('');
  });

  var vIdProduto = $('#selectProduto option:selected').val();
  var vProduto = $('#selectProduto option:selected').text();
  var mensagem = $('#msg');
  var linha = '<tr class="selected" id="linha' + vIdProduto + '">' +
        '<td>' +
        '<input class="idprod" type="hidden" name="idproduto' + vIdProduto + '" value="' + vIdProduto + '">' + vProduto +
        '</td>' +
        '<td>' +
        `<select class="form-control" id="autoriza">
          <option value="">Comprar</option>
          <option value="Sim">Sim</option>
          <option value="Não">Não</option>
        </select>`+
        '</td>' +
        '<td>' +
        `<select class="form-control" id="autoriza">
          <option value="">Comprar</option>
          <option value="Sim">Sim</option>
          <option value="Não">Não</option>
        </select>`+
        '</td>' +
        '<td>' +
        `<select class="form-control" id="autoriza">
          <option value="">Comprar</option>
          <option value="Sim">Sim</option>
          <option value="Não">Não</option>
        </select>`+
        '</td>' +
        ' </tr>'

  if($("tr#linha" + vIdProduto).length === 0) {
    $('#mytbody').append(linha);
  } else {
    $('#msg').html("<b class='text-danger'>&#9888; Produto " + vIdProduto + " já foi adicionado!</b>");
  }
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-10">
      <select class="form-control" id="selectProduto">
        <option value="A">Produto A</option>
        <option value="B">Produto B</option>
        <option value="C">Produto C</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
      <button type="button" name="button">Adicionar</button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
      <span id="msg"></span><br>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Produto</th>
            <th>Forn01</th>
            <th>Forn02</th>
            <th>Forn03</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="mytbody">

        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor seu problema? Estou confuso na sua pergunta rsrs.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno, posso sim. Nao posso deixar o sistema aceitar que o usuario compre o mesmo produto em fornecedores diferente, certo? Ex: Se ele marcar como sim no select forn01 o select forn02 e forn03 tera que ser não ou desbilitar entendeu?

Comment: Cara seu código está sujeito a gerar problemas, estão se repetindo os **ids** do `selects` criados.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno  LeAndrade , vou corrigir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como já foi dito, repetir id's é incorreto e traz problemas. Na verdade você nem vai precisar de id's nos selects, então remova-os todos.

Basta apenas criar esse evento que irá desabilitar os outros selects da mesma linha ao selecionar uma das opções:

```
$(document).on("change", "#mytbody select", function(){

   if($(this).val() == "Sim"){
      $(this).closest("tr").find("select").not(this).prop("disabled", true);
   }else{
      $(this).closest("tr").find("select").prop("disabled", false);
   }

});
```

Caso volte a selecionar a opção "Comprar" (que tem valor vazio), as outras opções são habilitadas de novo.

> Não entendi a função da opção "Não". Não bastaria apenas a opção "Sim"
>   e o que não foi marcado com "Sim" deixar vazio na option "Comprar"?

**Veja:**

```js
$(document).on("change", "#mytbody select", function(){
   
   if($(this).val() == "Sim"){
      $(this).closest("tr").find("select").not(this).prop("disabled", true);
   }else{
      $(this).closest("tr").find("select").prop("disabled", false);
   }
   
});

   $("button").click(function() {
  $('#selectProduto').change(function(){
    $('#msg').html('');
  });

  var vIdProduto = $('#selectProduto option:selected').val();
  var vProduto = $('#selectProduto option:selected').text();
  var mensagem = $('#msg');
  var linha = '<tr class="selected" id="linha' + vIdProduto + '">' +
        '<td>' +
        '<input class="idprod" type="hidden" name="idproduto' + vIdProduto + '" value="' + vIdProduto + '">' + vProduto +
        '</td>' +
        '<td>' +
        `<select class="form-control">
          <option value="">Comprar</option>
          <option value="Sim">Sim</option>
          <option value="Não">Não</option>
        </select>`+
        '</td>' +
        '<td>' +
        `<select class="form-control">
          <option value="">Comprar</option>
          <option value="Sim">Sim</option>
          <option value="Não">Não</option>
        </select>`+
        '</td>' +
        '<td>' +
        `<select class="form-control">
          <option value="">Comprar</option>
          <option value="Sim">Sim</option>
          <option value="Não">Não</option>
        </select>`+
        '</td>' +
        ' </tr>'

  if($("tr#linha" + vIdProduto).length === 0) {
    $('#mytbody').append(linha);
  } else {
    $('#msg').html("<b class='text-danger'>&#9888; Produto " + vIdProduto + " já foi adicionado!</b>");
  }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-10">
      <select class="form-control" id="selectProduto">
        <option value="A">Produto A</option>
        <option value="B">Produto B</option>
        <option value="C">Produto C</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
      <button type="button" name="button">Adicionar</button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
      <span id="msg"></span><br>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Produto</th>
            <th>Forn01</th>
            <th>Forn02</th>
            <th>Forn03</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="mytbody">

        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Não posso me arrepender e trocar de fornecedor?

Comment: isso tá meio miado, tem que explicar ao usuario esse esquema

Comment: não é isso, eu digo na página tem que instruir o usuario tipo `amigo se vc quiser mudar de fornecedor selecione a opção "Comprar" (que tem valor vazio) e escolha outro fornrcedor

Comment: Seria até válido, mas como eu achei a opção "Não" desnecessária, nem fui perder tempo com isso.

Comment: Na verdade, isso deveria ser um radiobutton.

Comment: Agora chegou onde eu queria

Comment: Obrigado Sasm, excelente exemplo, vou implementar. Vacilei nos ids mesmo. Ref ao Nao realmente nao faz sentido. Em relação ao radio estou com dificuldade no momento de receber isso no php pois tenho que usá-lo com (name[]) dai da um erro para inserir no banco.

Answer (score 2):

O mais sensato para esse tipo de formulário seria utilizar `input type radio`

Quando uma opção `RADIO` é marcada, esta só será desmarcada quando outra opção `RADIO` **com mesmo NAME** for selecionada.

> Veja como funciona

```html
Produto A <input type="radio" name="prodA" value="Forn01"/>
<input type="radio" name="prodA" value="Forn02"/>
<input type="radio" name="prodA" value="Forn03"/>
<br>
Produto B <input type="radio" name="prodB" value="Forn01"/>
<input type="radio" name="prodB" value="Forn02"/>
<input type="radio" name="prodB" value="Forn03"/>
<br>
Produto C <input type="radio" name="prodC" value="Forn01"/>
<input type="radio" name="prodC" value="Forn02"/>
<input type="radio" name="prodC" value="Forn03"/>
```

Portanto seu código funcionaria assim: [veja esse form sendo recuperado no PHP](http://kithomepage.com/sos/Validar-linha-javascript.php)

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $('#selectProduto').change(function(){
    $('#msg').html('');
  });

  var vIdProduto = $('#selectProduto option:selected').val();
  var vProduto = $('#selectProduto option:selected').text();
  var mensagem = $('#msg');
  var linha = '<tr class="selected" id="linha' + vIdProduto + '">' +
        '<td>' +
        '<input class="idprod" type="hidden" name="idproduto' + vIdProduto + '" value="' + vIdProduto + '">' + vProduto +
        '</td>' + 
        '<td>' + 
        '<input type="radio" name="prod'+vIdProduto +'" value="Forn01">'+
        '</td>' +
        '<td>' + 
        '<input type="radio" name="prod'+vIdProduto +'" value="Forn02">'+
        '</td>' +
        '<td>' +
        '<input type="radio" name="prod'+vIdProduto +'" value="Forn03">'+
        '</td>' +
        ' </tr>'

  if($("tr#linha" + vIdProduto).length === 0) {
    $('#mytbody').append(linha);
  } else {
    $('#msg').html("<b class='text-danger'>&#9888; Produto " + vIdProduto + " já foi adicionado!</b>");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-10">
      <select class="form-control" id="selectProduto">
        <option value="A">Produto A</option>
        <option value="B">Produto B</option>
        <option value="C">Produto C</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
      <button type="button" name="button">Adicionar</button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
      <span id="msg"></span><br>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
    <form action="" method="post">
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Produto</th>
            <th>Forn01</th>
            <th>Forn02</th>
            <th>Forn03</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        
        <tbody id="mytbody">

        </tbody>

      </table>
              <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Isso mesmo. Fica bem melhor.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno Sam e Leo. Tentei fazer dessa forma porem tenho que usar o name do input  como name[] dai da erro no momento de recuperar os dados no php.

Comment: @frodrigues, como assim `usar o name do input como name[]` ? E a qual input vc se refere?

Comment: Estou usando php com Laravel. No controllher quando recebo os requests para colocar dentro do laço para inserir no banco ele me da uma mensagem de objeto nao cotabil se nao colocar o name com chaves na frente.

Comment: Ex:   $cont = 0;
    while($cont < count($idproduto)){
      $detalhe = new RequisicaoDet();
      $detalhe->idrequisicao=$requisicoes->idrequisicao;
      $detalhe->idproduto=$idproduto[$cont];
      $detalhe->qnt=$qnt[$cont];
      $detalhe->detalhe=$detalhes[$cont];
      $detalhe->idcentrocusto=$idcentrocusto[$cont];
      $detalhe->save();
      $cont=$cont+1;
    }

Comment: Me refiro ao input de produto ok.

Comment: @frodrigues, blz, de Laravel entendo chongas :)

Comment: Kkkk. Vlw ja ajudou bastante.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente iremos remover os `id="autoriza"` dos seus `select`, pois eles estão duplicados e isso é um problema.

Agora iremos adicionar uma nova classe nos seus `select` para podermos reconhecê-los no JavaScript. Coloque todos igual o código abaixo:

```
<select class="form-control select-comprar">
```

Por fim, adicione o JavaScript para tratar a habilitação e desabilitação dos selects:

```
$('.select-comprar').on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "Sim") {
        controlarHabilitacaoSelectComprar(false, $(this));
    }
    else {
        controlarHabilitacaoSelectComprar(true, $(this));
    }
});

function controlarHabilitacaoSelectComprar(habilitar, coluna) {
    //Pegamos todas as colunas da mesma linha do select que alteramos o valor
    var siblings = coluna.parent().siblings();

    //Iremos realizar um loop em todos os selects que possuirem a classe que definimos como "select-comprar"
    siblings.find('.teste-select').each(function () {
        if (habilitar) {
            $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        else {
            $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $(this).val('Não');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Pedro muito bom